# getPendingTransactions does not work

Tags: go-ethereum

eth.getPendingTransactions() does not work, but i do have pending transactions on this node, observe:

```
> eth.getPendingTransactions()
undefined
> eth.getTransaction(eth.getBlock("pending").transactions[0])
{
  blockHash: "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  blockNumber: null,
  from: "0x7a5576dfeb32429899732a4183ea106407899a38",
  gas: 21000,
  gasPrice: 32000000000,
  hash: "0x1d8d962faa655d5064af340ff7047714316a686e4ed0682bb469e2ae26e0da59",
  input: "0x",
  nonce: 2,
  r: "0x3400fc118f587c4e779d8d33a8d367ee1f2226506bf6403ece32fb88880dfc8a",
  s: "0x77f7a872abd1737b0b2b6f3efc3e6e77fd0f87862f82cefc8495bd605a105eb5",
  to: "0x23a0e252e5114c21d5e601fcb7f3b6e341da48fd",
  transactionIndex: 0,
  v: "0x1f6",
  value: 2500000000000000000
}
>
```

Why doesn't it work? This transaction is EIP155 transaction, and I do have problems sending this type of transactions, they work with one blockchain but do not want to work with another. I wonder if some EIP field is hardcoded in the blockchain's Level DB database so geth thinks this blockchain is an old version and that's why it doesn't work, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The field `v` is a function of the parity bit of the X coordinate of the public key and the chainId. The chainId may be the reason why this isn't working.

```
if (tx._chainId > 0) {
    ret.v += tx._chainId * 2 + 8;
}
```

Originally, ret.v is either 27 or 28, and this works fine with local test chain, but will fail on public chains.